# Why does SqlDependencyEx stopps working after a while?

Tags: c#, asp.net, windows-services, sqldependency, sqldependencyex

I'm using SqlDependencyEX (monitor DB changes) and SignalR (notify registered clients) for an intranet monitor web application. When I start or deploy the application everything works fine but after a while, I don't get any change notification, in other words, it just stopped working. 
- Service Broker is enabled
- It runs with SA login

Would be very thankful for some help!

```
public static class DatabaseChangeNotifier
    {
        static Library.SqlDependencyEx _listener = null;

        public static void StartNotifier()
        {
            _listener = new Library.SqlDependencyEx("Server=DB-DB;Database=BLUB;Trusted_Connection=True;", "Techem", "FileShifterResults");
            _listener.TableChanged += Listener_TableChanged;
            _listener.Start();
        }
        public static void StopNotifier()
        {
            _listener.Stop();
        }

        private static void Listener_TableChanged(object sender, Library.SqlDependencyEx.TableChangedEventArgs e)
        {          NotificationHub.NotifiyClients(e.Data.Descendants("Name").First().Value);
        }
    }
```